# How come $ax^2+ ty^2 = z^2$ has no solution in $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

Let $a \in \mathbb{Q}^*$ be a non-square and let $p>2$ be a prime. 
Suppose $a \not \in (\mathbb{Q}_p^*)^2$(i.e. not a square in $\mathbb{Q}_p^*$) and the valuation of $t \in \mathbb{Q}$ with respect to $p$ is $1$. 
I would like to show that $ax^2+ ty^2 = z^2$ has no solution in $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Any comments would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Presumably, you want $x\neq 0.$ Then you want to solve $a=z_0^2-ty_0^2$ for some $z_0,y_0\in\mathbb Q_p.$

Comment: When $p=3,a=2,t=1$ there is a solution $x=1,y=1/2,z=3/2.$

Comment: Unless you mean $\nu_p(t)=1,$ that is $\|t\|_p=\frac{1}{p}$.

Comment: Can you show that for $a \in \Bbb{Z}_p^\times, t \in p \Bbb{Z}_p, Y \in \Bbb{Z}_p$ there is a solution for $aX^2+tY^2= 1 $ iff  $a\bmod p \in \Bbb{F}_p^{*2}$ ? The remaining cases reduce to that.

Comment: @reuns I think I can show what you mentioned (one direction follows by Hensel's lemma and the other just considering the equation mod $p$), but I'm actually not seeing how to reduce to this case... Could you possibly provide some details?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think the article means $v_p(t)=1$ as you stated.